# Meteor - Dynamically change collection name from function argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I need to dynamically control the Meteor collection by passing in an argument to the below function. The below function works, though would like to know if this is acceptable in the Javascript world, of if there is a better/best practices way to accomplish this. Any feedback is much appreciated. -Chris

```
function sortableListItems(divIDString, CollectionName) {  //pass in collection name
  this.$(divIDString).sortable({
  CollectionName.update({_id: Blaze.getData(el)._id}, {$set: {fontRank: newFontRank}});  // Collection name is replaced here by one of the arguments
  });
}

sortableListItems('#typography-items-js', TypographyCollection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just passing in a `Collection` instance and calling an update on it. I don't see any mechanical issues with this approach.

Given that you are using client-side operations to modify your DB, you may want to limit the collections which can be updated in this way. Have a look at [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) to prevent accidental data corruption.

Comment: Thank you! Generally I'm modifying the DB server-side. I'm using Collections2 and it's awesome. thank you again! -Chris